# reading several files in loop

Tags: r, csv

I have bunch of csv files which I want to read with R. When I use following code I get only the last file (in this case `file.100.csv`) which will be stored inside variable named `i`.

```
for (i in seq(10,100,10))
  i = read.csv(file=paste("file.", i, ".csv",sep=""), header=T, sep=",", skip=0, check.names=TRUE)
```

I want store every file inside separate variable named `10, 20, 30 ... 100`. I've also tried to store it in array:

```
for (i in seq(10,100,10))
 file_csv[[i]] = read.csv(file=paste("file.", i, ".csv",sep=""), header=T, sep=",", skip=0, check.names=TRUE)
```

But it gives me following error:

```
Error in file_csv[[i]] = read.csv(file = paste("file.", i, ".csv", sep = ""),  : 
  object 'file_csv' not found
```

Anyway, I'm not sure if R array can contain numbers which are not ascending by one but instead by ten. I guess for this purpose some kind of hash table would be more useful.

Comment: OK, so instead of loop I should use `lapply`, right? How can I then specify additional parameters for `read.csv` such as `sep`, `header`, `skip` etc.?

Comment: OK, seems like `lapply(c("file.10.csv", "file.20.csv"), read.csv, header=T, sep=",", skip=0, check.names=TRUE)` did the trick. But I still need to manually type filenames. So I've tried same manner for creating file names: `lapply(c(10,20), paste, sep="", "file.", ".csv")` but this put the numbers first in concatenation. Can you please also explain why my example with assigning to array did not work and post it as a question so I can accept it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your second approach: you have to create `file_csv` variable first.  Something like: `file_csv <- vector("list", 10); names(file_csv) <- seq(10,100,10)`.  Note as your file names are not sequential, you either have to use names, or introduce another index that runs from 1 to 10.

Comment: Assuming your files are in a reasonably organized directory, you can build a list of filenames with `list.files()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work because you assign the outcome of the read.csv to i (and not to the interpretation of i, for instance 1 in the first round of the loop). What you need is `assign`:

```
for (i in 1:10) {assign(paste0("variable", i), 5)}
```

With assign the variable name *is* interpreted. Running the above will assign 5 to variable1 -  variable10. In your case you would need

```
for (i in seq(10,100,10)) {
  assign(i, read.csv(file=paste("file.", i, ".csv",sep=""), header=T, sep=",", skip=0, check.names=TRUE))
}
```